# What is the Balatibala Mahamantra which was taught to Rama by Sage Vishwamitra?

Tags: ramayana, rama, gayatri-mantra, vishwamitra

In Ramayana we see that Sri Vishwamitra imparted a special mantra called "balA-atibalA" to Sri Rama and Lakshmana which is considered to be immensely helpful in both spiritual and materialistic domains.

What is this mantra and what is its significance?

Comment: Related: [Are Bala and Ati Bala mantras different from and superior to Gayatri mantra?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8912)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This mantra is very powerful and it looks like gAyatri mantra. It has additionally some beejas and other words hence it is a very long mantra. It is capable of slowly making one evolve to higher spiritual level of super-consciousness and helps one to go beyond the pull of lower forces.

We find its mention in [Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga22/balaitrans22.htm) when sage imparted this knowledge to Sri Rama and Lakshmana.

King Dasharatha sends Rama and Lakshmana along with Sage **Vishvamitra** as requested by the sage. In their course of travel, Sage Vishvamitra imparts a secret knowledge to the young princes Rama and Lakshmana, called **bala atibala** vidya-s, by practicing which nothing can wither their vigour and vitality.

**balaam atibalaam caiva paThataH taata raaghava || 1-22-14
na saubhaagye na daakSiNye na j~naane buddhi nishcaye |
na uttare prati vak{}tavye samo loke tava anagha || 1-22-15**

> "My dear Raghava, if bala atibala hymns are practised, oh, impeccable
>   one, none can equal you in the world by your handsomeness, calibre,
>   erudition, by your discernment, and even in replying or rebutting you.
>   [1-22-14b, 15]

**etat vidyaa dvaye labdhe na bhavet sadR^ishaH tava |
balaa ca atibalaa caiva sarva j~naanasya maatarau || 1-22-16**

> "On receiving these two teachings there will be none similar to you,
>   for bala and atibala are the mothers of all knowledge. [1-22-16]

**kSut pipaase na te raama bhaviSyete narottama |
balaam atibalaam caiva paThataH taata raaghava || 1-22-17**

> "Oh, best one among men, Raghava, if you go on reciting bala and
>   atiblala hymns, my dear Rama, there will be no hunger or thirst to
>   you. [1-22-17]

**vidyaa samudito raamaH shushubhe bhiima vikramaH || 1-22-21
sahasra rashmiH bhagvaan sharadiiva divaakaraH |
guru kaaryaaNi sarvaaNi niyujya kushika aatmaje |
uuSuH taam rajaniim tatra sarayvaam susukham trayaH || 1-22-22**

> Rama, the one with marvellous valiance, on obtaining those teachings
>   performed all his duties of a student in respect of a teacher and then
>   shone forth like the thousand rayed sun on a cloudless sky of autumn.
>   Then those three very happily stayed on the riverbank of Sarayu for
>   that night. [1-22-21b, 22]

[Balatibala Mahamantra:](http://www.homam.org/mantradocs/pages/Balatibala%20Mantra.html)

[image]

(103 letters , 158 mAtrAs) 
(Taken from **sAvitryupanishat of gopatha brAhmana**)

The purashcharana of this mantra is 1 lac 3 thousand times as the number of letters are these many. After the purashcharana one starts feeling the divine grace and becomes a medium of the divine power.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55970/discussion-on-answer-by-rakesh-joshi-what-is-the-balatibala-mahamantra-which-was).